# jquery indexOf problem with IE

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple select field and a jquery function that checks for a change in the select. the function looks for the value "Other", and if it's selected then displays an extra text field.

This is all working fine in chrome and FF, but for some reason IE throws an error on the indexOf function "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the code:

EDIT: 
Remember that this code actually works in chrome and FF. Is only IE that is throwing the error...

```
<select name="test" multiple="multiple" id="test">
 <option value="one">one</option>
 <option value="two">two</option>
 <option selected="selected" value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<input name="Name_Other" type="text" id="Name_Other" class="OtherDisplay" />


$.toggleOther = function (dd, txtOther) {
        if ($(dd).val() == null || $(dd).val().indexOf("Other") != 1) 
            $(txtOther).hide();

        $(dd).change(function () {
            var sel = $(this).val();
            if (sel != null && sel.indexOf("Other") != -1) { 
                $(txtOther).show();
            }
            else {
                $(txtOther).hide();
            }
        });
    }

$.toggleOther("#test", ".OtherDisplay");
```

Comment: I'm not a hundred-percent sure on this, but if you use the jQuery method [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/), instead of `indexOf()`, does it work?

Comment: what does .val() evaluate to in IE?

Comment: $(dd).val().index is not a function

Comment: .val() = "one,two,Other" if all the values are selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.toggleOther = function (dd, txtOther) {
        dd  =  $(dd);
        txtOther = $(txtOther);

        dd.change(function  () {
            var toggleBool = false;
            var sel  =  $.each($(this).val(), function(i,e){
                if (e.indexOf("Other")!=-1) toggleBool=true;
            });
            txtOther.toggle(toggleBool);
        }).change();
    };

$.toggleOther("#test", ".OtherDisplay");
```

the code is a little shorter than the original, and a little more powerful

this checks if any of the selected items are "Other" and if so, shows the Other text box. You see, your select box is a multiselect, so .val() returns an array (even if only one item is selected, see the docs), so we simply iterate through the array and check if any of them are the "Other" field.

alternatively, if you wanted to check if *only* the Other field was selected, you could replace the $.each with a simple array length check and then put the same conditional in.

lastly, if you wanted to make the code really flexible, and work for multiselects and not multiselects, just check what type of object .val() returns, so your code handles both stings and arrays appropriately (see the .val() docs).

Comment: it throws an error: Error: j is null: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js Line: 32

Comment: @user441365, you probably copied wrong, are you aware that your error dump is actually in jquery's code? jquery compiles fine, not to mention that my code doesn't even have 32 lines...

Comment: the j comes from the jquery.js file

Comment: @user441365, have you checked the jsfiddle link i posted?

Comment: yes I did, and that works fine, but when I copy and paste it onto my code it throws that error. weird

Comment: i find it difficult to believe that your code works before you paste that little snippet into it, and then suddenly throws an error, but whatever

Answer (score 3):

The truth is that IE dosen't handle Array.indexOf. That is the problem source.

You can create the handler:

```
if(!Array.indexOf){
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj){
        for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
            if(this[i]==obj){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

try using IndexOf, i had similar problem where indexOf was not working in few versions of IE.
IndexOf works well in all of the popular browsers and also in IE

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).val()` returns a native value (such as a String), not a jQuery object.  `indexOf` which you're executing against that apparently doesn't existi in IE.  Since this is almost certainly a string for you, try using `.match()` instead:

```
if (sel != null && sel.match(/Other/)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I believe Array.indexOf doesn't exsit, but string.indexOf should.

Comment: This suggests sel is not a string (which explains why `.indexOf()` didn't work either, but I'm not that familiar with IE).  See if sel is actually `undefined` or something like that.  Double check that jQuery actually selected something and that it selected what you expected it to (eg, `$(dd)[0].outerHTML`)

Comment: sel returns the same value that chrome and FF, the value of the item and yes, it's the correct value. weird.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `$(this).val()`, try using:

```
var sel = $(this).text();
```

Comment: This will check against the Text property of the selected option which may not be what OP wants.